# How to draw the whole picture at once in Python using turtle?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am making an analogue clock in Python using turtle. It has to be renewed every t seconds. For that, I am redrawing it every t seconds. I need it to be redrawn immediately (now it places all the elements one by one taking more than my t seconds). How can I do that? Actually, it does not have to be redrawn every t seconds, it's just the hands that have to move. Is there any other, easier way?

I have tried making speed 0 but that does not help. Maybe, there are some other ways to make the hands move?

```
turtle.reset()
turtle.speed(0)
while True:
    turtle.reset()
    clock_face.draw()
    hour_hand.showCurrentTime()
    minute_hand.showCurrentTime()
    second_hand.showCurrentTime()
    turtle.up()
    time.sleep(t)
```

Comment: Here's an example of an [analog clock using turtle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52959324/5771269).  The trick in this example is not to *draw* the hands but rather prefabricate turtles to *be* the hands.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `turtle.tracer(0, 0)` which will turn off animation and should significantly speed up your animation. If you decide to turn off animation, you will need to use `turtle.update()` at the end of your code.

However if you want it to animate every so often, the first parameter is some n value that will animate the n-th animation, and the second is a delay.

Some people have gotten things working very fast here:

[How to speed up python's 'turtle' function and stop it freezing at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16119991/how-to-speed-up-pythons-turtle-function-and-stop-it-freezing-at-the-end)

Comment: this answer should be a comment

Comment: The `turtle.update()` method needs to get called whenever you have the animation in a state that you want your user to see.  At the end of your code you should call `turtle.tracer(1)` to turn on automatic updates again and allow things like `turtle.hideturtle()` to work properly.