# Moving a specific sketch to specific point in Python Turtle module

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I'd like to program a graphical clock, which has three pointers, one for the hour, another for the minute and the last for the second. The time is synced with my local PC time, so I need the clock pointers infinitely move like a real clock, unless I end the program. How can I determine the moving clock pointers? Is there a function for that? I looked it up in Turtle's documentation, but found none. Maybe I've missed something. Here's my yet incomplete code:

```
import time
import os
import cursor
import turtle

cursor.show()
s = turtle.Turtle()
turtle.bgcolor('Black')
hour = int(time.strftime('%H'))
minute = int(time.strftime('%M'))
second = int(time.strftime('%S'))
s.pensize(5)
s.pencolor('Red')
s.circle(200)
s.penup()
s.goto(0,200)
s.pendown()
s.left(90)
s.forward(100) #how can I make this rotate 30 degrees???

turtle.done()
```

Thank you in advance :))

Comment: There is an example clock simulation in the built-in turtledemo folder that may guide you.

Comment: [Minimal turtle code to draw working clock hands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52959324/5771269)